# Set value to 0 if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Currently I get the average rating for each hour from my SQLite database with the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as avgRating, strftime('%H:00', date) as hour FROM ratings
WHERE questionId = 1 AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
GROUP BY strftime('%H', date);
```

Now I want that each hour that doesn't have any value at all, gets the average rating of 0, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical answers are (1) to do this in the applications and (2) to use a left join.  For the latter, you need a list of all hours, which can be cumbersome to produce.

In some cases, the hours are all present in the data, but they are filtered out by the `where` clause.  When this is the case, then switching to conditional aggregation is often the simplest way to get what you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN questionId = 1 THEN rating END), 0) as avgRating,
       strftime('%H:00', date) as hour
FROM ratings r
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')
GROUP BY strftime('%H', date);
```

This doesn't work in all cases, but if it does, it is a simple solution.